# Why don't water cuttings die of root asphyxia?

Tags: botany

Root asphyxia happens when there is not enough oxygen available for the roots, for example when the soil is clogged with water.
However it is common to do water cuttings where roots directly develop in water.

In this scenario, how is it possible for the roots to develop in only water without asphyxia, but they die of asphyxia in waterlogged soil?

Comment: Look up dissolved oxygen in water. In mud, other organisms compete for O2.